# Securing things to spars with a wire Cocky's Hitch

Tags: knots

I remember about a decade ago, my grandfather taught me a particular wire "knot".
He called it a **Cocky's Hitch**.
I remember the first step was to take a length of thick fencing wire and fold it in half.
and the last step was to put a screw driver though the bight, and twist -- wrapping it around the other end and drawing it tight.

But not the intervening steps. Or the fine detail of those steps.

I think we were using it to build a wind break, attaching some tin sheets or thick cloth to 
some star-pickets.

It could also be used to secure 2 spars to each other in the place of a lashing.

It is very strong.
my grandfather told me how back in the day they used to build houses out of it. I suspect they actually build farmsheds with it, and he was telling some stories.

Comment: This is tagged with [knots] because i can't think of a better tag, and don't have the rep to create one if i did.

Comment: It's going to be hard to find based on your description. It could be worth checking http://www.animatedknots.com/

Comment: @Liam: I don't think they do twisted wire.
It is not a knot so much as a method for twisting wire to make a strong join.

Comment: @Oxinabox Bit of a long shot, but came across this when googling looking for something that had your description? Names of things usually vary so ... [cobb & co hitch](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Tie-a-Cobb-Co-Hitch/)

Comment: @Aravona, yes that is it!

Comment: @Oxinabox let me form a proper answer for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wire knot comes under other names and I found it under a Cobb & Co hitch knot (another Australian name).

It requires wire, what you intend to tie together, a bolt or screw driver, and pliers to cut the wire.

> 1. Cut yourself a bit more than twice the length of wire to go around the job.
> 2. Fold the wire in half.
> 3. Pass the folded part (bight) of the wire around the job.
> 4. Put your lever (my bolt in this case) through the bight.
> 5. Use the lever to drag the bite around the other parts of the wire (this isn't easy to describe; hopefully you can see what I mean in the
>      pictures). NB Start the twist as close as possible to the job or you
>      will twist the wire off before it's tight.
> 6. Keep twisting the bight around the wire. The lever allows you to apply a lot of force and you will probably notice the wire cutting
>      into the timber. If you go too far at this point you will break the
>      wire and will have to start again.
> 7. When you are happy with the tension and the shape, cut the scratchy excess wire ends off to make it a bit safe.

[image]

Source: [How-to-Tie-a-Cobb-Co-Hitch](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Tie-a-Cobb-Co-Hitch/)

Comment: Cocky's hitch is also an australian name for it (being that I, and my grandfather, are australia).

Comment: Ahh fair enough! I'll just edit 'another' in ;)